# For $x, y \in \mathbb R$ prove this inequality:

Tags: inequality

For $x, y \in \mathbb R$
if $a>0, b>0 , c \in \mathbb R,$ and $ab>c^2$ Prove that $$ax^2 +2cxy + by^2>0
$$  I have tried adding and substracting a $2\sqrt{ab}xy$ but I'm having a hard time trying to prove this by only factoring,any help?

Comment: Divide both sides by $y^2$ and substitute $u=x/y$

Comment: @Gaffney This works!

Comment: Of course we also need to assume that we don't have $x=y=0$ (sorry to be so pedantic)

Comment: You are totally right!

Comment: Is there a general way to solve these quadratics in two variables?

Comment: Holding y to be a constant, evaluate the discriminant. The case of x being held constant is similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $f(x) = ax^2 + 2cxy + by^2 \implies \triangle' = (cy)^2 - aby^2 = (c^2-ab)y^2 \le 0$. Since $a > 0 \implies f(x) \ge 0$ as claimed.

Answer (score 1):

You have $a > 0$ and $b > c^2/a$, therefore
([completing the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square)):

$$
    ax^2+2cxy+by^2 = a \left( x + \frac ca y \right)^2 + \left(b - \frac{c^2}{a}  \right) y^2 \ge 0
$$

and the expression is *strictly positive* unless $x=y=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Although the post is kind of closed, but this may help.

Note that for every $u,v \in \Bbb{R}$ $$2|uv|\le u^2+v^2$$ (you can easily prove that by expanding both $0\le(u-v)^2$ and $0\le(u+v)^2$ and isloating $uv$ terms, or just simply referring to this as the AM-GM inequality.)

Since $a,b>0$, by setting $u=\sqrt{a}x$ and $v=\sqrt{b}y$ the above inequality becomes $$2|\sqrt{ab}xy|\le ax^2+by^2$$ The assumption $c^2<ab$ implies $0\le|c|<\sqrt{ab}$ and thus $$2|cxy|\le2|\sqrt{ab}xy|\le ax^2+by^2$$ Obviously $-2cxy\le|2cxy|$, so you can conclude $$-2cxy\le ax^2+by^2$$ which is equivalent to $$0\le ax^2+2cxy+by^2$$